# How to connect a CUPS printer to a Fedora box through a firewall?

Tags: fedora, firewall, cups, printer, lan

I have bought a new printer and connected it to my LAN/wifi with an Ethernet cable and I can access the printer from my phone. But when I try to add the printer to CUPS on a Fedora box that is also connected by wifi, the printer is not found. The Fedora box can ping the printer.

I am guessing that this is a firewall issue on the Fedora box. Fedora has a new firewall that uses “zones” and I do not understand it very well.  So I am hoping that someone could give me basic instructions at the “click on X then type Y in box Z” level.

I have raised this on the CUPS issue tracker but it seems that noone is looking there: https://github.com/apple/cups/issues/6031 This issue contains more details.

Comment: You are correct that certain ports need to be allowed through the firewall. [CUPS docs](https://www.cups.org/doc/firewalls.html) detail which ports need to be open depending on how you want to use the printer.

Comment: Thanks. The CUPS docs indeed make vague references to opening ports on the firewall. What I need to know is (a) which ports need to be opened (and whether tcp or udp) and (b) which "zones" these ports should be opened on using `firewalld` which the firewall installed on Fedora 35.